# Report Builder: How to have uniform horizontal gap between text boxes?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am working with Report Builder in SQL Server 2016.

I have 3 text boxes `Textbox1`, `Textbox2` and `Textbox3` one after another horizontally. They have same width and same height. Now I want to have uniform horizontal gap between those text boxes i.e. the horizontal gap between `Textbox1` and `Textbox2` should be same as the horizontal gap between `Textbox2` and `Textbox3`. How can I do that?

Thanks

### UPDATE:

Print screens of menus of Report Builder:

[Home Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqPbk.gif)

[Insert Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM6Xv.gif)

[View Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMbdv.gif)

Comment: What happens when you set the distance between them to the same value, either in points or inches?

Comment: How do you set the distance between them? I dont know this.

Comment: There is a properties box for the selected control which typically shows in the bottom right hand corner of visual studio.

Comment: The OP is using Report Builder in which case the properties window is accessed from the the View menu.

Comment: I know the property window of a selected control but which property I can use to set its distance from another control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the guide that appears when you put components close together (5 points, as I recall) there's no element that says "keep them this far apart.  To do what you describe, you have to do some math.

So let's say that your text boxes are 1.5 inches wide and you want them an inch apart.

First, you set the `left` property of TextBox1 to, say, 1.25 inches (for the margin).

Next, you set the `left` property of TextBox2 to 3.75 inches - the margin plus the width for TextBox1 plus your desired inch space.

Finally, you set the `left` property of TextBox3 to 6.25 inches - the margin plus the width for TextBox1 width plus the first desired inch space plus the width for TextBox2 plus the second desired inch space.

Does  that make sense?

Comment: It's a problem that I've had to solve many times before :).  If it works for you, remember to "accept" the answer - I'm told that will make it easier for others to find.

Comment: it works so I will accept it as an answer; I was hoping that **View > Alignment > Equal spacing** worked as the other answer suggest but that option is 
 not available to me

Answer (score 0):

You can either go to the properties of the textboxes under **Position > Left/Top**, or normally (I am not sure for this version) you find under **Home > Alignment > Equal spacing** while you select all textboxes.

Comment: When I select all textboxes I dont see **View > Alignment > Equal spacing** option

Comment: This is somewhere at the ribbon menue

Comment: I checked all the ribbon menus and I dont see it

Comment: I have updated the question to include print screens of all the menus

Comment: Its under **Home > Align > Equal spacing**. Check this option out. You have to select all the textboxes first btw.